# Find string in file and replace with value from another file for multilines - powershell

Tags: powershell

I would like to replace each string from one file A with value from another file B if string exist if no then add at end of string information "Link not exist". There is a small diffrent between files in. File A doesn't have number at end of each row which should be added from file B.

String from file A replace with string from file B*

```
L5020|http://linktosite.de|URL to L5020|http://linktosite.de|URL|P555
```

I tried to do so with csv map however without success as file A is changing every day, and if string change position or new string is added into file A then map is not working.

```
$file = "C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\URL\MAP.csv"
$mapping = Import-CSV $file -Encoding UTF8 -Delimiter ";"
$original_file = "C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\URL\fileA.txt"
$destination_file = "C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\URL\Output.txt"
$content = Get-Content $original_file  


for($i=0; $i -lt $content.length; $i++) {
    foreach($map in $mapping) {
     #If([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($content[$i])) {
       If ($InputString -like ($content[$i])) {
            $content[$i] = "$($map.HEADER1)|NOTEXIST" 
        }
        ElseIf ($content[$i] -eq "$($map.HEADER1)") {
                  $content[$i] = $map.HEADER2
        }
    }
}
```

There is a hundred lines in each file but files are not same
There is a few scenario:

1. File A have more rows then File B
2. File B have more rows then File A

FileA

```
L5020|http://linktosite.de|URL
L100|http://sitelink.de|URL
L50|http://abcde.de|URL
L511|http://bbcccddeee.de|URL
L300|http://link123456.de|URL
L5450|http://randomlink.de|URL_DE
L5460|http://randomwebsitelink.de|URL_DE
```

FileB

```
L5020|http://linktosite.de|URL|P555
L511|http://bbcccddeee.de|URL|P540
L100|http://sitelink.de|URL|P523
L50|http://abcde.de|URL|P53
```

Rsults for scenario 1:

```
L5020|http://linktosite.de|URL|P555
L100|http://sitelink.de|URL|P523
L50|http://abcde.de|URL|P53
L511|http://bbcccddeee.de|URL|P540
L300|http://link123456.de|URL|LINK NOT EXIST 
L5450|http://randomlink.de|URL_DE|LINK NOT EXIST 
L5460|http://randomwebsitelink.de|URL_DE|LINK NOT EXIST
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$fileA = Get-Content -Path fileA.txt
$fileB = Get-Content -Path fileB.txt

$result = @()
foreach ($lineA in $fileA) {
    $linkExistsInFileB = $false
    foreach ($lineB in $fileB) {
        if ($lineB -ilike "$lineA*") {
            $linkExistsInFileB = $true
            $result += $lineB
            break
        }
    }
    if (-not $linkExistsInFileB) {
        $result += "$lineA|LINK NOT EXIST"
    }
}
$result
```

Output:

> ```
> L5020|http://linktosite.de|URL|P555
> L100|http://sitelink.de|URL|P523
> L50|http://abcde.de|URL|P53
> L511|http://bbcccddeee.de|URL|P540
> L300|http://link123456.de|URL|LINK NOT EXIST
> L5450|http://randomlink.de|URL_DE|LINK NOT EXIST
> L5460|http://randomwebsitelink.de|URL_DE|LINK NOT EXIST
> ```